# map an specific website in host file in window

Tags: windows, iis

I have created an website in IIS as shown below and host name for this website is "arcmws".
[image: website in IIS]

My question is,
Is it possible to do something like below in the local host file(etc\hosts). ,

```
localhost/arcmws  arcmp
127.0.0.1/arcmws  arcmp
```

so that, when I type "http://arcmp/test.html" in the browser, the browser should open the "test.html" file.

Currently it is not working for me.

Comment: `hosts` file only emulates a local DNS server, so whatever you configure is restricted by what DNS can/cannot do. Therefore, what you wanted is impossible. You also seem to misunderstand what is the host name of a site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lex says, the host file only emulates a local DNS server. It will only work on local side.

The host file will only work with IP address and the domain, for example:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1  laravel.win
127.0.0.1   www.somedomaintest.com
127.0.0.1   www.olddomain.com
```

So if you want to use http://arcmp/test.html to access the arcmp web site, you should firstly edit the binding for the arcmp to use 80 port.

Like below image shows:

1.Modify the IIS web application bindings

[image]

[image]

2.Add record into the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   arcmp
```

Then you could use arcmp to access your IIS web application html file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. one more point, so the way this whole thing works. 
1) The moment we type http://arcmp" , local DNS will see that  "arcmp" is mapped to the "localhost OR 127.0.0.1" so it will go to the root directory of the IIS.      
2) Than it will look for the host name "arcmp" in the IIS.


I was little confused with the second part.

Comment: If you set the host name, the IIS will map the request to 80 port according to the host name. That means you could set multiple 80 web application inside IIS.

Comment: Thank You for the explanation.